# Using htmlentities 

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ckeditor, mathml

Hey everyone Im trying to retrieve mathml from a mysql database through a custom plugin I have created for CKeditor. But for some reason whenever paragraph tags are inserted with the mathml, the plugin I am trying to create refuses to open. I suspect this has something to do with using htmlentities. I would appreciate it if someone could provide some insight on how to apply htmlentities when retrieving the data in a selectbox of the plugin dialog. I actually want to know how to use the htmlentities function within items:

```
               items:[
                    <?php $i = 1;
               while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResource))
                  {

                     if($i == 1) {
                        echo "['$row[expressionname]','$row[mathexpression]']";
                        $i = null;
                     }
                     else
                        echo "['$row[expressionname]','$row[mathexpression]']";
                  }
               ?>],

                commit : function( data )
        {
            data.equations = this.getValue();
        }


              }]
```

Comment: Use "View source" in your browser, and update your question (click the "edit" link) with the source code corresponding to what you posted above. What needs to be checked is the code generated by PHP (the line starting with `items:[`).